# sugestions on how to speed up lambda function

Tags: python, pandas

Any suggestions on how to speed up this little code?

The code works fine, it's just too slow.

```
 df['business_day'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: isbday(x, holidays=holidays.US()))
```

My goal is to have a column that flags (true or false) if a given date is a business day, considering US holidays

Comment: What about it needs to be sped up?

Comment: `apply` is better then iterating the rows, but it's still going to be slow.  Where did the data come from?  Can you do this before you convert to pandas?

Comment: Where `holidays.US()` comes from?

Comment: If holidays.US() is a dataframe, then you might be able to join using `merge`, and specify some criteria.

Also maybe `df["date"].isin(holidays.US())` would create the appropriate T/F mask. I don't think the `isbday` function is needed if your holidays "list" only contains holidays (i.e. isn't a full calendar).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`np.is_busday`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.is_busday.html)

```
# Assuming date column is DatetimeIndex
hol = holidays.US(years=range(df['date'].dt.year.min(), df['date'].dt.year.max()+1))

df['business_day'] = np.is_busday(df['date'].astype(str).tolist(),
                                  weekmask='1111100', holidays=list(hol.keys()))
```

Output:

```
>>> df
        date  business_day
0 2011-07-03         False
1 2011-07-04         False
2 2011-07-05          True
3 2011-07-06          True
4 2011-07-07          True
5 2011-07-08          True
6 2011-07-09         False
```

Comment: I needed to add the following line of code so that the dictionary contains only the holidays and not the observed days as well.
     `hol = {key:val for key, val in hol.items() if not "(Observed)" in val}` Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're constructing the `US` instance again and again for every row you're checking.  Try constructing it just once, eg:

```
us_holidays = holidays.US()
df['business_day'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: isbday(x, holidays=us_holidays))
```

I'm not sure how much of an improvement you'll get time-wise but it'll definitely be more efficient than the way you currently have it.

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install swifter
```

and

```
import swifter
df.swifter.apply()
```